# mysql high read & write

Tags: mysql

I've been reading about high read or write but what about both, what would be your advice? In my case a high number of people are writing data and another set of people are reading it straight after, this is all web based and there are no pattern to determine who is writing or reading. Also because the data are changing several time per second they can't be cache, but the "cache size" could be increase to avoid mysql to issue I/O all the time.

One of the idea would be to use mysql cluster, but the data will have to be write to all nodes at the same time, what would be the impact in term of performance.

Seeking for advices.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be creating a replication setup. Where data is written into the master, data get replicated into the slave and reading is done from the salves

You can read more about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions-scaleout.html